# Local Disk E is not showing

Tags: disk

I installed Ubuntu 14 on Local Disk C and everything perfect but I cant find my other Local Disk E. Pls help me about that.

---

First of all Thanks a lot for your answer. But i m new on linux and I cant understand the solution. Can you help on this infos.

```
enes@enes-SATELLITE-C640:~$ sudo fdisk -I
[sudo] password for enes: 
fdisk: geçersiz seçenek -- I
Usage:
 fdisk [options] <disk>    change partition table
 fdisk [options] -l <disk> list partition table(s)
 fdisk -s <partition>      give partition size(s) in blocks

Options:
 -b <size>             sector size (512, 1024, 2048 or 4096)
 -c[=<mode>]           compatible mode: 'dos' or 'nondos' (default)
 -h                    print this help text
 -u[=<unit>]           display units: 'cylinders' or 'sectors' (default)
 -v                    print program version
 -C <number>           specify the number of cylinders
 -H <number>           specify the number of heads
 -S <number>           specify the number of sectors per track

enes@enes-SATELLITE-C640:~$
```

Comment: Thanx a lot bros but I cant understand guys what is the solution??

Comment: Just to be clear.  Why are you trying to find it?  Are you looking for documents, videos, or mp3s on it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `sudo parted -l` terminal command.

Comment: You enter a wrong command. Either in `fdisk` or `parted` `-l` is with "l" like in "lime". You can just copy text from here and paste to terminal. Do not retype.

Answer (score 1):

Linux does not assign drive letters (C:, D:, E:, ...) like Windows. It uses device files in the virtual file system tree.

Your first partition on the first hard disk (which would usually be C: in Windows) is called `/dev/sda1` in Linux/Ubuntu. The first HDD is `/dev/sda`, the second HDD is `/dev/sdb` and so on, while partitions are numbered starting with 1, so HDD1, partition 1 is called `/dev/sda1`. You understand the system?

That way you should be able to determine which name your E: partition from Windows has in Ubuntu.

If you don't know how your drives are partitioned, use the GUI program `gparted` (requires admin password) or the terminal output of `lsblk` or `sudo parted -l` (requires admin password) to display that information. It also shows e.g. partition size which will be helpful. Even in your Ubuntu file manager (Nautilus), all partitions should show up in the left bar, together with their name.

Comment: Better answher then the other ones!  Moved up!  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To show all mounted 'disks' other than 'C:', which in Linux are called partitions, type:

```
lsblk | grep /.
```

The `|`(bar) key is not any of `1`, `I`, or `L`.  You should see something like this.

```
└─sda7   8:7    0   120G  0 part /media/user/label
```

Your E: disk will be called something like `/media/user/label`